# How can to read the content of an ion input element?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have already tested this:

```
this.changedValue = document.getElementById("processID");
this.changedValueString = this.changedValue.value;
console.log("[INFO] Choosen processID: >" + this.changedValueString + "<");
```

Unfortunately, I get this with logcat:

> [INFO:CONSOLE(56878)] "[INFO] Choosen processID: >undefined<"

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look at [Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs) since you're trying to do things in an _old jquery way_ but things are done in a different way when working with Angular. That would help you to improve the performance of your apps (which is extremely important when it comes to Ionic apps).

Comment: Okey, i'll check this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [(ngModel)] in your input element like this,

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" />
```

and in your component.ts,

```
export class Page{
inputValue:string;
  constructor(){
    console.log(this.inputValue)
  }
}
```